# Vue 3 - component SSR not support

Tags: vue.js, server-side-rendering

```
if (process.isClient) {
  app.use(require('v-calendar'), {})
}


<client-only>
  <v-calendar />
  <v-date-picker v-model="date" />
</client-only>
```

`[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: v-calendar`

Comment: how to disable component in server? NUXT 3 bad im not using

Comment: Did you installed the package ?
Did you import the component ?

Comment: Yes, No, the bottom line is that the component is not imported on the server because it cannot work on the server side - and I think what to do on the server side it is possible to import some fake component so that there is no error

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.